# How to download bcache-tools with git?

Tags: linux

[This site](http://atlas.evilpiepirate.org/git/linux-bcache.git/tree/Documentation/bcache.txt?h=bcache-dev) says:

> You'll need make-bcache from the bcache-tools repository. Both the
>   cache device and backing device must be formatted before use.
>   make-bcache -B /dev/sdb   make-bcache -C /dev/sdc
>
> Wiki and git repositories are at:   http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org
>   http://evilpiepirate.org/git/linux-bcache.git
>   http://evilpiepirate.org/git/bcache-tools.git

Comment: Install `git` on your system. Read [the git book](http://git-scm.com/book). Have specific usage questions? Use `man git`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just, eg:

```
git clone http://evilpiepirate.org/git/linux-bcache.git
```

This creates and populates a directory.  There's a good introduction to using git beyond that, if you need to, here:

http://git-scm.com/documentation

Comment: At what directory I should do git clone?

Comment: Where ever you want it to exist, or you can specify a location after the repository address (see `man git-clone`).  You can move it afterward, in any case, it won't make any difference to anything.

Answer (score 2):

Git is a distributed source code control system. To download bcache for Linux, you have to clone the repository from their remote git repo like this:

```
git clone http://evilpiepirate.org/git/linux-bcache.git
```

You now will get a folder called linux-bcache where the source for bcache is saved which now you can compile and install.

Answer (score 1):

In laymen terms `git` is a tool or set of commands that used for version control operations. Git provides a way to have different versions of modified files either in local repository or remote repository.

Basic git commands

```
git init 
git logs 
git status 
git commit -m "My commit message"
git diff
```